# Why am I getting a no package error while installing tidy linter on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, tidy

Why am getting a no package error while installing tidy linter on AWS EC2 as attached, have done research but not getting solution for it.

**[ec2-user@ip-172-31-22-75 ~]$ sudo yum install tidy
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package tidy available.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error, because `tidy` is not in the repositories.

But you should be able to install it from the official **tidy website**:

- http://binaries.html-tidy.org/

For example:

```
wget https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/releases/download/5.4.0/tidy-5.4.0-64bit.rpm
yum install ./tidy-5.4.0-64bit.rpm
```

To **check** if it got installed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-78-126 ~]$ tidy --version
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.4.0
```